# Single dot textual form

Tags: syntax, formatting, symbols, text

How do I render a letter with a single dot above it?

I see `\[DoubleDot]` and `\[TripleDot]` are readily available, but what about a single dot?

Specifically I am after Q dot, which is used in thermodynamics. If it helps, here is [some background on Unicode and Q dot](http://www.personal.psu.edu/ejp10/blogs/gotunicode/2008/11/glyph-du-jour-thermodynamic-q-.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `OverDot`

`ref/OverDot` in the documentation (but one of those cases where you need to know what you want in order to be able to enter it)

```
OverDot[Q]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Strange this isn't in the Textual Forms panel of the Writing Assistant Palette, nor the See Also section of DoubleDot or TripleDot. Sorry it was so simple – my Google Fu failed me.

Comment: as per Vitaly's screen grab below, the palette has a template for overscript boxes which is what this actually is.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to Mike's post two things you can do:

- Type "Q" then press `Ctrl+&` and then type "." to enter with a shortcut.
- Use palette - there are actually a few you can use. For example go menu **Palette >> Other >> Basic Math Input** . This will bring a neat concise palette of frequently used input forms. Bottom left corner has what you need.

[image]

Little, but convenient things, - I use it often myself ;)